# Start Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, connection

I have been trying to figure out how to start with Oracle SQL, but I can't get the "Connection" to work. I'm not sure what the (connection name, username, password, etc.) fields are.

If I want to create a small database on local host, why do I need to connect in the first place.

I searched Google but still can't get it to work. Any help is appreciated.

***ERROR MESSAGE: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Developer is just a client utility that lets you connect to an existing database.  It sounds like you don't have a database to connect to yet.  If that's the case, you'd either need someone to create a database on another machine for you or you'd need to download the database software on to your local machine and create a database to connect to.  You can download the Oracle database from the Oracle Technology Network, the same place you downloaded SQL Developer from.  I would guess that you would want to download [Oracle 11.2 Express Edition](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/express-edition/downloads/index.html).

Alternately, you may want to download one of the VMs that Oracle has put together that has a lot of related software installed for you to use.  For example, [this VM](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/databaseappdev-vm-161299.html) has SQL Developer, Oracle 12.1, APEX, XML DB, and a number of labs already installed for you.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle SQL Developer is a tool to ACCESS existing database, you cannot create new database here. The connection is used to define where your existing database sits and how to connect to it. So you need to name you connection (bookmark), provide host name, where database runs and user name plus password to identify yourself.

Comment: Can you suggest me any alternative? (Oracle product)

Comment: Oracle express database - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/express-edition/overview/index.html. This will install your database instance on your computer. And then you will access tool like Oracle SQL Developer to access it (write your SQL commands and queries).